# Static method that takes an array of strings and returns an integer

Tags: java, return

I am still pretty new to programming and I am trying to do this small program where I write a static method that takes an array of strings and returns an integer. From there I have to find the index position of the smallest/shortest string and return that index value. I am completely lost and struggling with this. Can I get some help?

My code so far...

```
public class test 
{

    public static void main(String [] args) 
    {
      String [] Month = {"July", "August", "September", "October"};
        smallest(Month);
        System.out.println("The shortest word is " + smallest(Month));
    }

    public static String smallest(String Month[]) 
    {
        String first = Month[0];
        for (int i = 1 ; i < Month.length ; i++) 
        {
            if (Month[i].length()<first.length())
             {
                first = Month[i];
            } 
        } 
        return first;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the code below,

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String [] args) 
    {
      String [] month = {"July", "August", "September", "October"};
     //   smallest(Month);
        System.out.println("The shortest word index position is " + smallest(month));
    }

    public static int smallest(String Month[]) 
    {
        String first = Month[0];
        int position=0;
        for (int i = 1 ; i < Month.length ; i++) 
        {
            if (Month[i].length()<first.length())
             {
                first = Month[i];
                position=i;
            } 
        } 
        return position;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is actually pretty close, but --if I understand your task correctly-- instead of the actual smallest element, you should keep track of the index only, since that is what you want to return in the end.

```
public static int smallest(String[] months) {
    int first = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < months.length; i++) {
        if (months[i].length() < months[first].length()) {
            first = i;
        } 
    } 
    return first;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Focusing on the `smallest` method.

```
public static void smallest(String[] month) {
    // since we have no knowledge about the array yet, lets
    // say that the currently known shortest string has
    // size = largest possible int value java can store 
    int min_length = Integer.MAX_INT, min_length_idx = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < month.length; i++) {
        // is this current string a candidate for a new minimum?
        if (month[i].length() < min_length) {
            // if so, lets keep track of the length so that future
            // indices can be compared against it
            min_length = month[i].length();
            min_length_idx = i;
        }
    } 
    return min_length_idx;
}
```

This method will then also cover the case where the array does not have any strings in it, i.e., empty array.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int smallest(String month[]) {
   int smallest = 0;
   for ( int i=0; i<month.length; i++ {
     if (...) {
       smallest = i;
     }
   }
   return smallest;
}
```

Note: use standard conventions where variable names begin with a lower-case letter.